# show data on JSP using Hbase REST or Hive queries?

Tags: jsp, hadoop, hbase, hive

How can I show HBase data on a JSP? Should I use Hbase REST or Hive queries? Which will take less time?

Comment: you can also use the Java API... why you do not consider this option ?

Answer (score 1):

HBase APIs (REST, Java or thrift) will provide better performance. But you should model your data carefully so that it will be optimal for your intended queries.